# Why some English words getting removed after using stop words or nltk corpus?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, nltk, data-cleaning

I am working with pyspark dataframes and I need to perform data cleaning on one of the columns as shown below:

```
df.select('words').show(10, truncate = 100)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                               words|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[you, are, hereby, ordered, to, cease, and, desist, all, furthe, r, emails, to, this, address, im...|
|[content, type, text, plain, charset, utf, 8, content, transfer, encoding, quoted, printable, x, ...|
|[you, are, hereby, ordered, to, cease, and, desist, all, furthe, r, emails, to, this, address, im...|
|[, original, message, return, path, bounce, 19853e, 6fb54, visyak, 3djuno, com, cysticacneonchin,...|
|[, forwarded, message, return, pat, h, bounce, 19853e, 6fb54, visyak, 3djuno, com, cysticacneonch...|
|[, original, message, from, 248, 623, 1653, mailto, lisa, lahlahsales, com, 20, sent, tuesday, fe...|
|[2018, horse, trailer, closeouts, free, delivery, cash, back, click, here, to, view, it, online, ...|
|[, original, message, from, paypal, us, mailto, scottkahndmd, nc, rr, com, sent, 27, february, 20...|
|[2col, 1, 2, 09, client, specific, styles, outlook, a, padding, 0, force, outlook, to, provide, a...|
|[you, are, hereby, ordered, to, cease, and, desist, all, furthe, r, emails, to, this, address, im...|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

I perform the following steps for data cleaning:

```
remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol='words', outputCol='words_clean') #remove stop-word
df = remover.transform(df)

df = df.withColumn("words_filtered", F.expr("filter(words_clean, x -> not(length(x) < 3))")).where(F.size(F.col("words_filtered")) > 0) #remove words with less than 3 characters

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
@F.udf('array<string>')
def remove_words(words):
    return [word for word in words if wnl.lemmatize(word) in nltk.corpus.words.words()] #removing words that are not in nltk corpus

df = df.withColumn('words_final', remove_words('words_filtered'))
```

I get the output as shown below:

```
df.select('words_final').show(10, truncate = 100)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                         words_final|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[hereby, ordered, cease, desist, address, immediately, authorities, provider, continued, failure,...|
|[content, type, text, plain, content, transfer, printable, apparently, yahoo, tue, return, path, ...|
|[hereby, ordered, cease, desist, address, immediately, authorities, provider, continued, failure,...|
|[original, message, return, path, bounce, received, sender, bounce, tue, pst, results, received, ...|
|[message, return, pat, bounce, received, sender, bounce, tue, pst, results, received, ass, receiv...|
|                                                       [original, message, sent, ball, subject, get]|
|[horse, trailer, free, delivery, cash, back, click, view, horse, magazine, index, option, archive...|
|[original, message, sent, subject, notification, payment, number, hello, payment, amount, payment...|
|[client, specific, styles, outlook, padding, force, outlook, provide, view, browser, button, body...|
|[hereby, ordered, cease, desist, address, immediately, authorities, provider, continued, failure,...|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

I see that stop words (`are, the, in,` etc) and many junk words such as `scottkahndmd` or incomplete words such as `furthe` are removed. But there are few words like `emails, tuesday, february, encoding, quoted, online` are also removed. There could be more such English words which might be getting ignored.

Any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it looks like filtering happens in several places:

1. the `StopWordsRemover` removes [common words](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/resources/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/stopwords/english.txt), like, `he`, `she`, `myself`, etc.  Usually these words may not be very useful in the text models, but that depends on the task that you're trying to solve
2. another layer of filtering is your `WordNetLemmatizer` - it could be the main culprit of removal of `email`, `encoding`, etc.  Try to tune it, to be less  aggressive in removal of the words

P.S. if you're doing NLP on Spark, I would recommend to look to the [Spark NLP](https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp) package instead.  It could be more performant, have more functionality, etc.